# Assign multiple values to one latch

Tags: verilog

I need a latch which can take multiple bus with one enable signal for each and when this signal is high, the latch takes the value of the associated bus, something like this :

[image]

I tried this :

```
module Test (
    input [1:0] load,
    input [15:0] bus,
    output reg [7:0] value
);

    wire [7:0] temp;
    
    assign temp = (load[0]) ? bus[7:0] : (load[1]) ? bus[15:8] : 8'bZZ;
    
    always @(load or temp) begin
        // Latch value
        if (load) begin
            value <= temp;
        end
    end
    
endmodule
```

and this :

```
module Test (
    input [1:0] load,
    input [15:0] bus,
    output reg [7:0] value
);
    
    always @(load or bus) begin
        // Latch value
        if (load[0]) begin
            value <= bus[7:0];
        end
        else
        if (load[1]) begin
            value <= bus[15:8];
        end
    end
    
endmodule
```

And this same warning appears on both (repeated for each bit) :

> Warning (13012): Latch Test:test|value[0] has unsafe behavior
>
> Warning (13013): Ports D and ENA on the latch are fed by the same signal load[0]

The only way that I found to avoid these warnings is like this :

```
module Test (
    input [1:0] load,
    input [15:0] bus,
    output [7:0] value
);
    
    reg [15:0] temp;
    reg index;
    
    always @(load or bus) begin
        if (load[0]) begin
            index <= 0;
        end
        else
        if (load[1]) begin
            index <= 1;
        end
        
        // Latch value
        if (load) begin
            temp <= bus;
        end
    end
    
    assign value = temp[8*index+7 -:8];
    
endmodule
```

But it's a waste of memory because it saves the two buses instead of one, is it possible to do it with one reg and avoiding these warnings ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can get rid of the warnings in the first two examples—you have a bonafide race condition between the latch enable and the data feeding the latch. It is more obvious in your first example.

When `load` goes to 0, `temp` will be changing to Z ( a *don't care* most likely 0) at the same time the latch enable goes to 0. Which one happens first is clearly a race.

Comment: I don't understand how there is a race condition because if load = 0, no matter if temp is processed first or last, latch value will not change, no ?

Comment: The issue is when load = 1 and then goes to 0, what value gets latched? The data input to the latch might change before the enable goes low. It's a physical race.

Comment: So, it's possible to have temp changing to ZZ and at the same time have latch still enabled and taking this value ? And for the second example ? is it because it is synthesized like the first example ?